# Add scolling to a user control having multiple Expander controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollview

I have a UserControl in my WPF application which needs to have 3 Expander controls oriented Vertically.

```
     <Grid  Margin="0,-3,0,0" Height="430" Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions/>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="430" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Expander Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" MinHeight="0"  MaxHeight="220" Height="Auto" Header="Auto Create Well Pad" OpacityMask="#FFECF5F5">
                    <Grid Margin="5,5">
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
                <Expander Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="Auto" Header="Scenario well pads" OpacityMask="#FFECF5F5">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="0,5,0,0" OpacityMask="#FFECF5F5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        ...
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Expander>
                <Expander Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,5" Height="Auto" Header="Project Well Pads" IsExpanded="{Binding ShowAvailablePads}" OpacityMask="#FFECF5F5">

                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

With the above XAML code, the scroll bar does appear but on expanding/collapsing the expander controls, the scroll bar does not become active.

Note: All expanders have different controls inside them and when they expand, scroll bar should become active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need set the *`Height`* for `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
... />
```

Because from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A `ScrollViewer` enables content to be displayed in a smaller area than its actual size. When the content of the `ScrollViewer` is not entirely visible, the `ScrollViewer` displays scrollbars that the user can use to move the content areas that is visible.

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you should set the height on the `ScrollViewer` instead of the `StackPanel`.

If you set a fixed height on the `StackPanel` it will never become bigger, so when expanding the `Expanders`, if the content can no longer fit inside the `StackPanel`, it will just clip the remaining content and not show it.

So the point is to make the `StackPanel` grow freely by not setting the height explicitly,
and then have the `ScrollViewer` take over when there is no more room.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="430">
    <StackPanel>
        ....
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```